# Correct pronunciation of "Can"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, ae-raising

How to correctly pronounce word "can" in British English and in American English?

Here's somehow related [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/13204/7454) but it is more about differences between "can" and "can't", and I'm interested how to pronounce "can" in American English and in British English.

Comment: Have a look at [this site](http://www.forvo.com/word/can/#en)

Comment: Thanks! Cool site... but there's no samples from Great Britain :(

Comment: Also, many of those may be pronunciations for *can* as in *soda can* rather than the verb *can*. If you look at the related question linked above, it says that in American dialects, the verb *can* rhymes with *men*. But the noun *can* usually rhymes with *man*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OED (British pronunciation):

> kæn\

From Merriam-Webster (American pronunciation):

> \kən, ˈkan also ˈken; dialect ˈkin\

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) is an IPA reference, in case you are unfamiliar with the symbols used.

Answer (score 0):

To me the AE pronuciation allows more sound to the "e" whereas as a BE speaker I would pronounce hardly any "e" sound and it would sound shorter, more like "kan" such that it ryhmes with the word "pan"

Answer (score 0):

I speak American English. I hope it's not discouraging to you to hear, Dmitry, but "can" is an extremely common word and the pronunciation changes in subtle ways according to the context it's used in.

In American English "can" is often shortened and pronounced as kn with the vowel of ə or ɪ being mostly hummed during the n sound.

Other times when there's more emphasis being given, the vowel might shift to a longer and very nasally æ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from California and how I personally say the words is *can* is pronounced the same as the name *Ken* whereas *can't* is pronounced like how most people say *can* and the "t" isn't pronounced.