# When to use "cannot" versus "can't"?

Tags: differences, negation, contractions, modal-verbs

When is it best to write "can't" versus writing "cannot"? Are they interchangeable in every situation?

Comment: *Can't* is less formal than *cannot*. That's the only difference.

Comment: I would personally insist on using *cannot* where the emphasis is on '*not*': using *can't* in such a case would kind of drown out the more significant '*not*' part. @Robusto I suspect it is not that simple (actually, hope not). Let's wait and see what the others have to say.

Comment: @Robusto: there is no unawkward way to uncontract "Why can’t I". Related: [Is it incorrect to say, “Why cannot…?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50251/is-it-incorrect-to-say-why-cannot)

Comment: Related to what @Kris says: [How can I distinguish “can” & “can't” from pronunciation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13189/how-can-i-distinguish-can-cant-from-pronunciation)

Comment: @RegDwight АΑA: Why can I not uncontract it unawkwardly?

Comment: @SF "Why can't I" => ??? it's not "*Why cannot I?" The best I can think of is "Why is it I cannot?"

Comment: @Matt Эллен: "Cannot" is already a contraction of "can not" (it is, isn't it?), so uncontracting it one level more (and then splitting normally) seems okay to me. Replace "Can't" with "Don't" and uncontract that.

Comment: @SF it seems awkward to me.

Comment: @SF I'm formulating my question in the form of an hypothesis:

Does "Why can I not have some bacon" sound awkward, as it is, in formal circumstances, only in fringe cases applicable? For example: "You can not have bacon because it is out of our reach." While for a denied request one would use "Why may I not have some bacon?" The use of 'can' instead of 'may' is already an informal speech pattern. Moreover, a denied request is unusual in formal settings, questioning it would be quite awkward per se.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Grammatically, you can use **can't** instead of **can not** or **cannot** in the majority of circumstances. There is an exception. In [wh-movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Wh-movement_in_English), the contraction should not be expanded unless you *also* change the word order:

> **Why can't I have some bacon?** //OK
>   **Why cannot I have some bacon?** //not OK, archaic
>   **Why can I not have some bacon?** //OK again, although formal

Stylistically, the choice between can't and cannot is more complex. Generally, people use **can't** in speech and informal writing, and **cannot** or **can not** in formal writing or very formal speech. Also (as @Kris points out in a comment), **cannot** might be used when you need to carefully distinguish it from **can't** in speech.

Comment: BTW, the OED says that the one-word construct *cannot* is "the ordinary modern way of writing *can not*" with a space between it, which apparently is archaic, or non-modern, or some such.