# "Why can I not" vs. "Why can not I"

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions, negation

Consider the following two sentences:

> Why can I not open the door?

and

> Why can not I open the door?

**Which is more common? What's the subtle difference between them?**

Answer (score 2):

The former is definitely more common; the latter sounds rather dated, and interpretations may vary depending on the different connotations that it could provoke. The second option is often found in its contracted form, though: "Why can't I open the door?".

Have a look at [this question on *cannot* versus *can't*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78935/when-to-use-cannot-versus-cant) and the [*wh*-movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Wh-movement_in_English) it references. Note that the example in that answer is nearly identical to yours, and it opts for the former or contracted form.